# Unit Testing with ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Unit Testing.. first of all i want to know how we do unit testing in ASP.NET MVC.

In My project i am using MVC5 and Web API2. I want to implement unit testing within my project.

can anyone of you tell me how to start and provide me some links to approach?

Comment: search [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com)

Comment: Thank you.. do you have any good links?

Comment: this should get you started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUf6g3smIlY

Comment: click on that link and search in there :) @NaveenGupta

Comment: Thanks Zaki.. I got some idea by watching this video.. now i will try to implement in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

http://www.developerhandbook.com/2013/08/30/csharp-writing-unit-tests-with-nunit-and-moq/

-It is good introduction to mocking and AAA approach.

You can use NSubstitute instead of Moq if you want - it is more popular and you can find more examples about NSubstitute.

Comment: please add description in your answer. link can be unavailable in future